# Python Falsk __name__

Tags: python, flask

In a default Flask app, PyCharm generates the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In almost all of the tutorials I'm following (socketio, right now), It wants me to add initialization code within the if statement (like so):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), app)
```

**QUESTION**

`__name__` seems to always equal `app` Which means `__name__` does not equal `__main__` and therefore will not enter this if statement. What exactly is the purpose of this if statement? Is it PyCharm specific or maybe some way to start the application in production? If so, how does production automatically set the `__name__` to `__main__`?

Trying to figure out where these variables come from so I can figure out proper placement of code (ie: socketio).

Reference: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `app = Flask(__name__)` does not mean that `__name__` equals `app`.  For one thing, there's a `Flask` in the middle.

Comment: I used `print(__name__)` and it printed `app`

Comment: You may want to read [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/744178)

Comment: @jwodder Thanks for the link. That answer my question!